# Best way to implement single enumeration only Moq IEnumerable

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, ienumerable

While refactoring a project I ran into an issue where consumers of an `IEnumerable<T>` method assumed that the returned enumeration could be enumerated many times. This is no longer true, the application throws `NotSupportedException`: "**Only a single enumeration is supported by this IEnumerable.**"). There are many unit tests (using XUnit and Moq), but they did not catch this because they would use `List<T>` as the IEnumerable implementation. Now I want to make the unit tests expose this error.

I came up with the following implementation, which seems to work the way I want.

**My questions**:

1. Is there some easier way of doing this in general (c#, regardless of Moq)?
2. Is there some easier, built-in way to do this in Moq specifically?

```
public class DataTransferObject
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public interface IDemoClient
{
    IEnumerable<DataTransferObject> GetData();
}

public class OnceEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    private IList<T> _data;
    private int position = -1;

    internal OnceEnumerator(IList<T> data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    public T Current => _data[position];

    object IEnumerator.Current => _data[position];

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        position++;
        return (position < _data.Count);
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Reset(): Only a single enumeration is supported by this IEnumerable.");
    }
}

public class OnceEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private OnceEnumerator<T> _enum;
    private bool _enumReturned = false;

    public OnceEnumerable(IList<T> data)
    {
        _enum = new OnceEnumerator<T>(data);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (_enumReturned)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("GetEnumerator(): Only a single enumeration is supported by this IEnumerable.");
        }
        else
        {
            _enumReturned = true;
            return _enum;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var client = new Mock<IDemoClient>();
        client.Setup(c => c.GetData()).Returns(new OnceEnumerable<DataTransferObject>(
            new List<DataTransferObject> {
                new DataTransferObject { Title = "foo" },
                new DataTransferObject { Title = "bar" }
            }));

        var data = client.Object.GetData();

        // enumerate once...
        if (data.Any(x => x.Title == "biff"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("found biff");
        }

        // I get the behaviour I want:
        // System.NotSupportedException : GetEnumerator(): Only a single enumeration is supported by this IEnumerable.
        if (data.Any(x => x.Title == "boff"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("found boff");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not following...what specific implementation can't be enumerated more than once?

Comment: In this case we're using Microsoft's OData client to retrieve data from a MS Dynamics system. This behaviour can be found with WPF clients, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104249/cancel-dataservicecollection-only-a-single-enumeration-is-supported-by-this-ien

Comment: In this case most of the methods return data using Microsoft's oData client (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/client/getting-started) and the IEnumerables as a rule do not support enumerating more that once. Rather than start doing ToList() inside the getter methods to return lists because _some_ consumers loop over the result several times, I want to add ToList() only to those consumers that need it.

Comment: @davidl basically any enumerable that reads from network has such behavior.

Comment: Ahh, right, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such functionality built-in. But your code can be simplified if you'll use the fact that auto-generated iterators don't support the `IEnumerator.Reset` method:

```
public class OnceEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> source;
    private bool isEnumeratorRequested;

    public OnceEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (isEnumeratorRequested)
            throw new NotSupportedException();

        isEnumeratorRequested = true;
        return EnumerateSource().GetEnumerator();

        IEnumerable<T> EnumerateSource() // You cannot reset this
        {
            foreach (var item in source)
                yield return item;
        }
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

I would also create an extension method to easily convert any enumerable into once enumerable:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AsOnceEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) =>
     new OnceEnumerable<T>(source);
```

Usage:

```
dtos.AsOnceEnumerable()
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I'm using your code (I just added the text "Only a single enumeration is supported by this IEnumerable." to the NotSupportedException, to avoid the cryptic "Specified method is not supported."